# Assigning value to variable in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to write following query in snowflake

```
Declare firstName varchar;
Declare lastName varchar;

select firstName =FirstNameColumn,lastName =LastNameColumn from User;
```

Comment: Hi , do you mean something like this using the SET,  

create table user1 (FirstNameColumn varchar2(100),LastNameColumn varchar2(100) );

insert into user1 values('Him', 'K');

SET firstName = 'Him'; 
SET lastName = 'K';

select firstName =FirstNameColumn,lastName =LastNameColumn from User;
select * from user1 where FirstNameColumn = $firstName and LastNameColumn = $lastname;

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare session variables, and you can use SET command to initialize/assign a value to a session variable:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html#initializing-variables

```
create table names (fname varchar, lname varchar ) as select 'Gokhan','Atil';

set first_name = (select fname from names);
set last_name = (select lname from names);

select $first_name, $last_name;

+-------------+------------+
| $FIRST_NAME | $LAST_NAME |
+-------------+------------+
| Gokhan      | Atil       |
+-------------+------------+
```

Unfortunately, there is a bug when assigning multiple varchar variables like this:

```
set (first_name, last_name) = (select fname, lname from names);

Assignment to 'FIRST_NAME' not done because value exceeds size limit for variables. Its size is 16,777,216; the limit is 256 (internal storage size in bytes).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET MY_VARIABLE2 = (
                    SELECT T2.V FROM T2 WHERE T2.C = 'FOUR'
                   );
SELECT $MY_VARIABLE2;
```